# Unable to reconnect to an ODBC connection

Tags: c, odbc, informix

I am working with C and ODBC on RedHat Linux.  I have an application which connects, disconnects and reconnects to an Informix database.  The application actually works fine on an HP 32 bit Server, however, I am unable to reconnect (SQLConnect error - Invalid Argument Value) on RedHat 64 bit Linux. The arguments have not changed at all since the original connection (which works fine). Has anyone seen this problem in the past?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar problem with password: http://groups.google.pl/group/comp.databases.informix/browse_thread/thread/4bd42eaa7b1f4ca7/badd0ec570a79654?q=ODBC+%22Incorrect+password+or+user%22+%22not+known+on+the+database+server%22&rnum=5#badd0ec570a79654

My solution was to connect with password, if it fails connect with empty password and if it fails again connect with password. Sounds strange, but it works for me.

Also you can create simple code that shows that error. Then enable ODBC tracing and show us results.